# How do I document generated classes in Yard?

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

I have a class that I create from a factory function like this:

```
Cake = MyProject.Struct(:type, :price)
```

In Yard, it's simply displayed along with my constants:

```
Cake =

        Struct(:type, :price)
```

I want it to show up in the "Classes: " list. After reading up on the docs, I was lead to believe that this would work:

```
# @!parse class Cake; end
Cake = MyProject.Struct(:type, :price)
```

But it literally changed nothing.

Is it possible to get Yard to document dynamically created classes as classes?

Answer (score 1):

It has been quite some time since this was asked, but while googling for an answer myself, I was lead here, and figured to post my solution in case anyone else stumbles here.

I found that this solved it:

```
class Cake < Struct.new(:type, :cake)
end
```